# How to sort std::vector but do not change specific elements using std::sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I have a vector which contains positive integers and -1. My problem is I want to sort the vector but dont touch `-1 elements` by just using `std::sort`(I know other approaches to solve it).

For example:

> Input: [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]
>
> Output: [-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190]

This is my idea to solve it but it didnt work:

```
sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), [&](const int& a,const int& b)->bool {
        if (a == -1 || b == -1)
            return &a < &b;
        return a < b;
    });
```

> My output is: [-1, 150, 170, 190, -1, -1, 160, 180]
>
> The output should be: [-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190]

Is there any idea to solve it by using `std::sort` ?

Comment: I don't think it is directly possible. The `std::sort` function operates on a range and there isn't a way to remove the elements temporarily and add them back at the same positions later (of course you can do this in multiple steps but I believe that is not what you are asking). I also don't get what you mean by "customize" `std::sort`. And also how `std::sort` works is implementation defined AFAIK so you can't make any assumptions about how the ordering happens.

Comment: @Yashas sorry for my english, you are right, i edited my question

Comment: Extract the locations of  `-1`s to a vector, erase all `-1`s, sort and pipe them back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::sort` cannot do that. It sorts a range of elements in accord with a strict, weak ordering. The ordering you define is not [strict-weak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). And there's no way to define an ordering that is strict-weak, such that certain values remain in their current positions. And therefore, if you attempt to use `sort` with such an ordering, you get undefined behavior.

So you're going to have to write your own sorting function. Or you can remove the -1's (recording their positions), sort the list, then reinsert them.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done using [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) alone. Alternative is to extract the locations of `-1`s, erase all `-1`s, sort the vector and reinsert where appropriate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{ -1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180 };
    std::vector<int> vtemp;
    auto it = v.begin();
    while ((it = std::find_if(it, v.end(), [](int x){ return x == -1; })) != v.end()) {
        vtemp.push_back(std::distance(v.begin(), it));
        it++;
    }
    v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), -1), v.end());
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (auto el : vtemp){
        v.insert(v.begin() + el, -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: there are obvious optimizations to improve speed (esp on reinserting the -1s) but this is a reasonable approach.  You can even do it without additional space by storing the positions of the -1s in the vector itself, as you squash them out.